# Как рассчитать радиус?

Tags: математика, геометрия

Извиняюсь за название, просто я не знаю как назвать тему. Дело вот какое..
Представьте что у Вас в руках равносторонний-прямой угол и плоскость, на которой одной стороной лежит этот угол. Теперь найдите мнимый центр и поверните этот угол так, чтобы вторая его сторона заняла место первой. Понимаю что не понятно поэтому иллюстрация ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я поверну угол на 90 градусов вокруг точки `O`, то отрезок `CA` займет место отрезка `AB`.

Теперь представьте что угол 45 градусов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне найти длину радиуса `OE` чтобы отложив от отрезка `AB` перпендикуляр равной длины, я нашел точку, повернув угол вокруг которой на 45 градусов я поместил отрезок `CA` в положение `AB`?

Comment: Хочу добавить то, что второй рисунок рисовался на глаз и сторона под углом 45 градусов не соответствует действительности.

Comment: нарисуйте пож-ста исходное и конечное положение угла. я не понимаю из вашего объяснения задачи :(

Comment: и причем тут перпендикулярная плоскость, если все происходит в одной плоскости?

Comment: @soon А Qwertiy не про это же самое написал?

Comment: @splash58, да, верно. Почему-то SO не показал плашку с новыми ответами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условие, то точку O надо поместить в точку пересечения биссектрисы угла BAC и срединного перпендикуляра к отрезку AB.

В общем, равнобедренный треугольник AOB с основанием AB, угол OAB равен половине угла BAC. Надо найти высоту. Для этого есть несколько способов разной сложности.

Comment: А можно формулу?

Comment: @shatal, упс.. формула была неверная.

Comment: после прочтения ответа ниже, захотелось сказать Вам спасибо за подробное объяснение.

Answer (score 3):

Так это же очень просто, как мне кажется. Обозначим через `x` половину отрезка `AB`, он же будет половиной `АС`, радиус `R` должен быть таким, чтобы окружность касалась отрезка AB, и отрезка AC, деля их пополам в точках касания (доказательство этого факта обсуждается в 9-м классе на геометрии, что касательные, выпущенные из одной точки, имеют равную длину до момента касания окружности). Дальше получаем уравнение `x/R = tg Pi/8`. Отсюда `R = x / (tg Pi/8)`. Величину `x` я так понял, Вы знаете. Тангенс `Pi/8` равен корню из частного двух разностей: первая разность это корень из двух минус один, а вторая корень из двух плюс один.